# Update field to another object

Tags: apex, trigger

Im a newbie please bear with me.
I need to update the status field in the contract object with the stage in the oppotunity. My code does not work. Please help.

```
trigger ActivateContract on Opportunity (after update) {
List <Contract> cont_List = new List <Contract>();
List <Opportunity> opp_List = new List <Opportunity>();
Set <ID> oppId = new Set <ID>();

for (Opportunity oppo : Trigger.new){
    oppId.add(oppo.AccountId);
    }
    cont_List = [Select Id, Status__c, Active__c FROM Contract WHERE AccountId IN : oppId];     
    for(Contract cont : cont_List){
        for (Opportunity oppor : Trigger.new){
        cont.Status__c = oppor.StageName;
        update cont;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update cont_List instead of **cont**

Try below code.

```
 trigger ActivateContract on Opportunity (after update) {
List <Contract> cont_List = new List <Contract>();
List <Opportunity> opp_List = new List <Opportunity>();
Set <ID> oppId = new Set <ID>();

for (Opportunity oppo : Trigger.new){
    oppId.add(oppo.AccountId);
    }
    cont_List = [Select Id, Status__c, Active__c FROM Contract WHERE AccountId IN : oppId];     
    for(Contract cont : cont_List){
        for (Opportunity oppor : Trigger.new){
        cont.Status__c = oppor.StageName;

    }

}
update cont_List;
}
```